# React Native, Drop shadow for rounded View

Tags: react-native

How can I drop shadow for rounded View.

I'm setting borderRadius to a value for round corners. But elevation property makes it square again. And without elevation it won't drop a shadow.

The code I'm using is

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.box}></View>
</View>
```

And for styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 60,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#efefef",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    flexDirection: "column"
  },

  box: {
    width: "95%",
    height: 250,
    elevation: 1,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
});
```

Comment: Please post relevant parts of your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the shadow radius with `shadowRadius`, example:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    elevation: 8,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 2,
      height: 2
    },
    shadowRadius: 5, // <- Radius of the shadow
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 16,
    margin: 8,
  },
})
```

Check out the ShadowProps documentation in React Native docs:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props